# Stop Python enumerate() from splitting a string into characters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, enumerate

I have a function that takes a list of keyword arguments and calculates a bunch of results based off the list of keywords, and I'm using enumerate to structure the loop so as to output a data table with all of the results. Everything works great when the list of parameters is greater than one but when only a single parameter is passed, enumerate thinks it wants to split that keyword up into individual letters. The obvious way around this would be to just drop the enumerate call and use a counter variable but is there any way to work with the enumerate function to disallow this behavior?

Below is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

params = ("x**2","x**3","x**4")

chars = {
   "x**2": lambda x: x**2,
   "x**3": lambda x: x**3,
   "x**4": lambda x: x**4
}

Matrix, names = np.zeros((x.shape[0], len(params)+1)), ["x"]
Matrix[:,0] = x[:]
for counter, param in enumerate(params, start=1):
    Matrix[:,counter] = chars[param](x)
    names.append(param)

panda_matrix = pd.DataFrame(Matrix)
panda_matrix.columns = names

print(panda_matrix)
```

and like I said, I get what I want when there are multiple params available to enumerate:
[image: resulting output]

but when I pass only a single parameter, enumerate thinks it wants to split that up into a bunch of individual characters.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1mike\PycharmProjects\libRL\example.py", line 41, in <module>
    Matrix[:,counter] = chars[param](x)
KeyError: 'x'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any way around this?

Comment: Do some type checking. If params is not a tuple, turn it into one.

Comment: That worked. Though I kept playing with it and found if the user inputs the params as for example ['x'] or {'x'} instead of ('x') then python interprets it right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out, `('x')` looks like it might be a tuple, but it's not. `('x',)` is a tuple, and `'x',` is a tuple... but expecting your users to know this seems unreasonable.

The suggestion to turn things into tuples is fine, but be careful: `tuple('ab')` is `('a', 'b')`, so you're back to square one. But you could check to see if `params` is a string with `isinstance(params, str)`, and deal with it if it is:

```
if isinstance(params, str):
    params = (params,)
```

There is another approach, but it may or may not be better. NumPy has a handy function, `atleast_1d()`, which checks that an array has at least one dimension. Maybe overkill here, but it's good to know:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.atleast_1d('x**2')
array(['x**2'], dtype='<U4')
```

You could always cast this back to a tuple with `tuple()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would even recommend the type-sniffing portion. `params` is meant to be an iterable of `str` values, so `params = ('x**2',)` would be the preferred solution.

Comment: Okay, but if you have 'x**2' to start with... I agree that checking types is not all that Pythonic, but sometimes we want to be flexible, e.g. lots of NumPy and SciPy functions handle scalars or ndarrays.

Comment: Checking types is not Pythonic? I definitely disagree. What else was all the fuss about when type-checking and typed arguments was introduced into core?

Comment: The fuss is kind of what I was getting at. I'm not getting into religious warfare on here - just trying to help someone out. Take it or leave it.

Comment: I get what you all are saying, but just from user experience I don't know if it would be more weird to require a comma after a single input parameter or to just require users to use a list or set as the input. The objective here is that params is a function argument like def func(x, y, params={"x **2","x **3","x **4"}, **kwargs) so users can choose which lambdas they want to activate via that dictionary 'chars'.